Material UI Stepper make the connector line and stepIconComponents touch?
I would like to connect the dots essentially for the Material UI stepper when it is vertical.
I have done it for the horizontal component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-feather-5plgnr?file=/src/Demo.tsx:571-628

However this was done using
[`&.${stepConnectorClasses.alternativeLabel}`]: {
    top: 10,
    left: "calc(-50% + 0px)",
    right: "calc(50% + 0px)"
  },

The alternativeLabel is used for the horizontal steppers - how can I connect the dots for the vertical stepper?:
So I can have something like this:

